# Nonlinear liabilities for pension funds

Tags: hedging

I'm reading about hedging for pension funds, I understand why we hedge the liabilities but what I don't understand is the concept of nonlinear liabilities ? what do we mean by that ? can someone explain this concept ?

Comment: Where did you see this?

Comment: @BobJansen in my internship :)

Comment: Sure, but what was the context.

Comment: for pension funds plans we often talk about hedging linear and nonlinear liabilities, I'm having troubles understanding what we mean by the two ? @BobJansen

Comment: To me linear hedging means hedging based on the Duration of the liabilities, non-linear means taking into account Convexity (quadratic) and perhaps higher order terms.

Comment: I agree with @noob2, that is a possible interpretation. Another interpretation could be that some of the claims of the participants have a non-linear relation with some financial instrument. For example, unit linked policies with a guarantee.

Comment: might also be tail risk hedging or otherwise using options.

Comment: @BobJansen can you please care to explain what you mean by unit linked policies with a guarantee?

Comment: AFAIK this is more popular as an insurance product but: The capital of a policy holder with a unit linked product is linked to a basket of stocks. To protect the policy holder the guarantee is basically a put option the policy holders has on this basket.